# Run a bash including a variable in the "bash XXX.sh" command

Tags: bash, variables, include

I am completely new to "programming" in Linux, and I wonder if it is possible to include the definition of a variable when I run a bash file.

My bash file needs the variable in order to go from one or another path, so I would like to be able to include it when running the script.
Something like this:

```
bash MYFILE.sh -VARIABLE
```

So the -VARIABLE would be used in the script.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of shell parameter expansion to smoothly read variables from the environment of the parent process, if it's that what you want to achieve.

Look at the following script named `test.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash 

VARIABLE=${VARIABLE:="default value"}

echo $VARIABLE
```

If you start it with the line

```
$ ./test.sh
```

it outputs

```
 default value
```

But if you invoke `test.sh` with the line

```
$ VARIABLE="custom Value" ./test.sh
```

it outputs

```
 custom value
```

But make sure that the variable assignment is at the beginning of the line. Otherwise it is passed to `test.sh` as command line argument.

The used form of parameter expansion `${parameter:=word}` is described in the bash reference manual as:

> If parameter is unset or null, the expansion of word is assigned to parameter. The value of parameter is then substituted. Positional parameters and special parameters may not be assigned to in this way.